# Progressive Web App - No Manifest Detected

Tags: html, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I am building a Progressive Web App and would like to add a manifest file.  I have built one and added a link to it on the home page but I get a message that says, "No manifest detected".  Here is what the head looks like in index.html:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="application-name" content="app">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="app">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#233b69">
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#233b69">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="/index.html">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="assets/img/app.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="assets/img/app.png">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Here is what the manifest.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "someApp",
  "short_name": "app",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#233b69",
  "icons": [
{
  "src": "assets/img/app.png",
  "sizes": "192x192",
  "type": "image/png"
}
  ]
}
```

Comment: did the below solution help?

Comment: Did it help? Was there another answer as I have the same problem...

Comment: for me the issue was with an invalid markup (my <link> tags were attached to a wrong parent element because of a typo)

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like the manifest file and the index.html is not in the same path or not linked correctly. If it is and still not working, try changing manifest link like below (added "/" in the href),

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Where do you see the error msg "No manifest detected"? If you can attach the screenshot of what you are getting and also the Chrome developer tool -> network and Application tabs screenshot, we could get whats going with it.

Answer (score 4):

Check your index.html file, manifest.json file and service-worker.js file are in root(same) folder.
if it is, then check inspect element and go to application menu. see screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. In this form it's just a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed: sometimes need to close the tab and reload the page to get manifest to re-initialize.

Possibly caused by caching the manifest file... and then not re-initialized in DevTools after cache update. Best guess, hard to tell.